# Map float to a partition possible in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point

Suppose I have a partition (where each partition is a continuous range) over a range of floats:

`R = [a_0, a_n)`

`P(R) = [a_0, a_1), [a_1, a_2), ... , [a_n-1, a_n)`

For any given float `f` in `R`, is there a constant-time (in the number of partitions, `n`) way of mapping `f` -> `[a_i, a_i+1)`?

My intuition strongly suspects there is not - so, what's the best we can do then?

Comment: The answer to this question depends significantly on your model of computation.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Turing

Comment: ^ LOL           But seriusly, I also cannot imagine what "model" could be meant here

Comment: Does each partition have the same size ?

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous: *"constant-time (in the number of partitions, n)"* - if it was really constant, this would mean that it would **not** depend on the number of partitions. Do you mean linear, O(n)? (Although this would be a trivial loop...)

Comment: What's the incentive here? Why is simple logarithmic time not enough here? If that's asked for not practical reason and for theory sake, consider asking in cs.SE

Comment: @JulienD Would be pretty easy if that was the case :P So no, can't make that assumption.

Comment: @Marco13 No, I meant constant -- then immediately stated I didn't believe such a solution existed (though I cannot prove it) - and asked what the best we could do is. Clearly we can do linear, so was wondering if we could do better

Comment: @amit Application is in continuous collision detection of 2 polygons with many vertices - but the general problem certainly applies to other applications as well

Comment: And why is logaritmic time (binary search) not enough for your purpose?

Comment: Is te partition constant? Can you do any preprocessing?

Comment: Turing machines don't have floats. VtC unclear what you're asking.

Comment: So I guess the answer will be some elaborate form of: "You can easily achieve logarithmic time, and constant time can only be achieved **iff** you can do some preprocessing **and** some advantageous preconditions hold".

Comment: @anon: Some problems involving *convex* polygons can be solved in surprisingly quick times using a cool technique called "rotating calipers".  Worth googling to see if it fits your problem.

Comment: Well, floats are a discrete set, so in *theory*, yes, there's a constant-time solution: simply create a lookup table whose indices correspond to *all* floats in the range `[a_0, a_n)`. Whether that theoretical solution is practical or not is going to depend on what other practical constraints you have.

Comment: @amit I mean, the faster the better right? Certainly can do logarithmic. Lots of vertices, and a very tight CPU budget :(

Comment: @m69 For each shape, the partition is constant. Many different shapes (all defined at compile-time) Yes, preprocessing encouraged.

Comment: @Marco13 How? Which preconditions?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, convex! Ill look into it, thank you

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ha - sure :P

Comment: Surprisingly, the "preconditions" that I mentioned actually referred to something *similar* to what @MarkDickinson said. For example, imagine the segments describe percentages (i.e. values between 0 and 1, with 2 fractional digits), like `(0.00-0.21),(0.22-0.58), (0.59-0.99)`. Then you could create a mapping of the 100 values to the segments. More generally, this can be applied when there is a reasonable discretization, meaning that the whole range can be transformed into *any* (small) range of *integral* numbers where each element can unambiguously mapped to its containing segment.

Comment: @Marco13 If I can impose restrictions on my geometry, that may turn out to be a great idea!

Comment: Actually, one (and maybe THE) crucial question here is the precision. Will the ranges be of the form `(0.0000001 - 0.0000002),(0.0000002-5000)`, or will they be more "regular"? Would it be OK to map the whole range to the interval (0.0 - 1.0), and then use a precision of maybe 0.01 or 0.001 to represent the actual segments within this range?